# converting multiple arrays from xml to json with staxon

Tags: java, arrays, json, xml

I'm using Staxon to convers xml files to json. Unfortunately I have a following issue:

```
<reference>
<io_FOOTER ioID="200163832-ZFN">
</io_FOOTER>
<io_PRODBEN ioID="200019098-ZPV" highlight="1" detail="1">
</io_PRODBEN>
<io_PRODBEN ioID="200019099-ZPV" detail="1">
</io_PRODBEN>
<io_PRODBEN ioID="200019100-ZPV" onlyMiele="1" highlight="1" detail="1">
</io_PRODBEN>
<io_FOOTER ioID="200163832-ZFN">Patent: EP 2454977 B1</io_FOOTER>
<io_PRODBEN ioID="200019103-ZPV" onlyMiele="1" highlight="1" detail="1">
</io_PRODBEN>
<io_PRODBEN ioID="200019132-ZPV" onlyMiele="1" detail="1">
</io_PRODBEN>
<io_PRODBEN ioID="200019134-ZPV" detail="1">
</io_PRODBEN>
</reference>
```

In effect I see that Staxon identifies first three io_PRODBEN nodes as an array, they are seperates with io_FOOTER then he stumbles upon the next three io_PRODBEN nodes and I guess he overwrites the first array with it ? Is there a wey to make STAXON append the first array?

My marshaler setup is as follows:

```
private static final JsonXMLConfig JSON_XML_CONFIG = new JsonXMLConfigBuilder()
            .autoArray(true)
            .autoPrimitive(true)
```

A big issue is that I actually use this unmarshaler and parser to parse tons of different xml files to json so I can't make some kind of hack here just to deal with this specific use case. I also don't have control over contents of the xml input.

Optimal output for me would be two arrays. One with two io_FOOTER elements and one with six io_PRODBEN elements

Comment: What JSON did you expect to get from that mixed-content XML?

Comment: 2 arrays. one with two io_footer elements, one with six io_prodben elements. I understand that the xml structure is a problem here. I just wonder if I can fix it on my side.

Comment: That would be wrong, since that changes the order of the elements. Try again. What should the JSON look like, so the order is retained? If using array, the 8 elements in a single array needs to know their type, so you can have mixed elements in a single array. There are other ways, though.

Comment: 8 elements in an array cold work as well. So something like:

{"reference": [
all 8 elements 
] 
}

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml).